# Lifetime and closures and continuation passing style

Tags: rust

I'm playing with Rust closures, trying to get a feeling for them, and one task I set for myself was to implement an in-order traversal with continuation-passing-style. Usually something I can do in about an hour in other languages, but here I've managed to get stuck on how to manage the lifetime of a closure I use in callback.

I've defined a binary tree like this, which is pretty straightforward:

```rust
// A node is a tuple of (left, value, right)
struct Node<T>(pub Tree<T>, pub T, pub Tree<T>);
// A tree is an optional pointer to a node
type Tree<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;
```

and I can do a direct recursive traversal the way I would expect:

```rust
// Direct recursion.
// The <T: Copy> is needed because we copy values into
// the result vector. For other usages we might not need it
fn inorder<T: Copy>(t: &Tree<T>, res: &mut Vec<T>) {
    // If t is not empty it is Some(node)
    if let Some(node) = t {
        // Pull out the values of the node.
        // In the development branch of Rust there is
        // a nicer syntax, but this is how it is now
        let Node(left, val, right) = node.as_ref();

        inorder(left, res);
        res.push(*val);
        inorder(right, res);
    }
}
```

To do it with continuations, however, I need to define closures to manage the rest of the traversal and pass those along with a tail-recursion, and my immediate solution looked not much different from my current one:

```rust
// Ideally, we wouldn't need to pass the vector along with the closures
// but Rust won't let us hold on to a mutable reference in a closure if
// another closure also has a mutable reference, so we pass the vector
// from continuation to continuation instead.
fn cps_rec<T: Copy>(t: &Tree<T>, res: &mut Vec<T>, 
                    k: Box<dyn FnOnce(&mut Vec<T>)>)
{
    match t {
        None => { k(res) },
        Some(node) => {
            let Node(left, val, right) = node.as_ref();
            let after_left = |v: &mut Vec<T>| { 
                // After we have gone left, add v and go right, 
                // calling k when we are done
                v.push(*val);
                cps_rec(right, v, k);
            };
            cps_rec(left, res, Box::new(after_left));
        }
    }
}

fn cps<T: Copy>(t: &Tree<T>) -> Vec<T> {
    let mut res = vec![];
    cps_rec(t, &mut res, Box::new(|_| ()));
    res
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=20e51c70248db6e6b17640c4c6bb86de)

The problem is in the recursion `cps_rec(left, res, after_left)` where the lifetime of the closure doesn't match the constraint. (I think, I can't say I fully understand exactly what Rust is complaining about, but the problem goes away as soon as I make the closure's body empty, so it is something in the inferred lifetime there that is messing things up). I first suspected that it was the lifetime of `val` or `right` that was fighting me, but it doesn't help to put `move` in front of the closure after dereferencing them

```rust
fn cps_rec<T: Copy>(t: &Tree<T>, res: &mut Vec<T>, 
                    k: Box<dyn FnOnce(&mut Vec<T>)>)
{
    match t {
        None => { k(res) },
        Some(node) => {
            let Node(left, val, right) = node.as_ref();
            let val = *val;
            let right = *right;
            let after_left = move |v: &mut Vec<T>| { 
                // After we have gone left, add v and go right, 
                // calling k when we are done
                v.push(val);
                cps_rec(&right, v, k);
            };
            cps_rec(left, res, Box::new(after_left));
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ec8e1d6b4a24bf40aafa8c39ab8283ad)

so I can't work out what the problem is, or how to tell Rust that this closure will survive long enough to complete the recursion...

I then tried using a generic type for the continuation, seeing if that would make Rust resolve the issue for me:

```rust
fn cps_rec<'a, T: Copy, Cont>(t: &'a Tree<T>, res: &'a mut Vec<T>, k: Cont)
    where Cont: FnOnce(&'a mut Vec<T>)
{
    match t {
        None => { k(res) },
        Some(node) => {
            let Node(left, val, right) = node.as_ref();
            let after_left = |v: &'a mut Vec<T>| { 
                // After we have gone left, add v and go right, 
                // calling k when we are done
                v.push(*val);
                cps_rec(right, v, k);
            };
            cps_rec(left, res, Box::new(after_left));
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1021503111fe9e430c9065f8e2b88592)

but that breaks the compilation when the type checker has to recurse on the type inference. Maybe not surprising since the type of the closure probably depends on the inferred type of the recursion.

Is there something I can do to fix this, or is the idea dead on arrival and I have to try a completely different approach if I want to make something along those lines?

Comment: Nitpick: `if let Some(node) = t { let Node(left, val, right) = node.as_ref();` this is redundant, you can do just `if let Some(Node(left, val, right)) = t {`.

Comment: Ditto in `cps_rec()`.

Comment: I tried that, but `let Some(Node(left, val, right)) = t` doesn't work because I have an `&Option<Box<Node<T>>>`. That is why I did it the ugly way. With `box_patterns` I can get a nicer syntax, but I'm not using this on nightly. (It is ugly, though...)

Comment: Oh the `Box`. Yeah, it's ugly.

Comment: Would you mind posting the full errors you get with each attempt? (A link to the playground will also be good). I think I can reproduce, but I want to be sure.

Comment: I added Playground links under the different attempts.

Comment: You can `match` on `option.as_deref()` and it should work.

Comment: Yes, that is *much* nicer, thanks!

Comment: I tried to reproduce, polished a little bit the code, and now it compiles without any errors. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=05340b6b5d107a8feca356b78901fd59

Comment: I'm really interested in the reason your generic code initially did not work. It works on the playground.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. When I actually call the code, the type inference needs to work out the type of the function, and then I hit an infinite recursion. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=207189bca0eed1a44d9da233ed190465

Comment: Oh there is additional code. Let me look at it, if I'll get into conclusions I'll update my answer. It's always good to know _why_ :P

Comment: The additional code is just a call to the function. That is when Rust tries to figure out the concrete time from the generic, and that is where it has to do an infinite recursion. It makes sense enough, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifetime problem is becaue `Box<dyn FnOnce(&mut Vec<T>)>` is actually, with lifetimes explicitly specified, `Box<dyn FnOnce(&mut Vec<T>) + 'static>`. That is, it requires the closures to be `'static`. A closure is static if everything it captures is `'static`. Of course an empty closure fulfills this condition - it captures nothing, so it worked if you emptied its body.

However, your closure captures over non-`'static` references - `val` and `right`. I'll soon explain why copying them doesn't work.

The solution is simple: we don't really need the closure to be `'static`; we can be fine even if it won't be - we don't store it or something. To express that to the compiler, we need to change `Box<dyn FnOnce(&mut Vec<T>)>` to `Box<dyn FnOnce(&mut Vec<T>) + '_>` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1f41a36419657b15aa5d799093534c5e)). That's it. `'_` is the *explicitly elided lifetime*: it tells the compiler "figure the right lifetime out yourself". Usually the compiler does that automatically, but with `dyn Trait` he sometimes gives up and just uses `'static`. The lifetime is inferred according to the [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html); in this case, it introduces a new lifetime, like if we wrote:

```rust
fn cps_rec<'elided_lifetime, T: Copy>(
    t: &Tree<T>,
    res: &mut Vec<T>,
    k: Box<dyn FnOnce(&mut Vec<T>) + 'elided_lifetime>,
) { ... }
```

What confuses here is the compiler's error message. It'd be clearer if you'd followed the compiler's suggestion and put `T: 'static` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7752ec2c956bf5d11c5a1faa3511abae)):

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:17:32
   |
6  | fn cps_rec<T: Copy + 'static>(t: &Tree<T>, res: &mut Vec<T>, k: Box<dyn FnOnce(&mut Vec<T>)>) {
   |                                  - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
17 |             cps_rec(left, res, Box::new(after_left));
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cast requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

This is what I said. `'static` is required because of the closure's implied `'static` bound.

But the compiler is has something more important to tell you (or rather, yell at you). It thinks: "given that the closure requires `'static`, those references are obviously `'static`. This user isn't lying to me, he's a good citizen!" Only later it'll realize it was wrong, but it will never get to this "later" because it will stop compilation due to errors earlier. But as of now it thinks, "given that those references are *obviously* `'static`, they're `&'static T` (for `val`, or `&'static Option<Box<T>>` for `right`). But for `&'static T` to be valid, `T: 'static` must hold (imagine a reference like `&'long &'short i32`: you'll be able to access it for `'long`, but as long as `'short` is over it's invalid, and you will use a dangling reference!). Can I prove that `T: 'static` always hold? Nope! Well, should emit an error." (You can fill a bug report at https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues, the Rust developers will appreciate it even though I'm not sure how much they can do to improve the situation).

Why copying them didn't help? First, the way the compiler thought about it hasn't changed, and so the same error is still emitted. Second, even if we could solve it (for example by specifying `T: 'static`), there is another error   ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d86d6397d2f409c44432ea3f240c1af9)):

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*right` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/lib.rs:12:34
   |
12 |             let right: Tree<T> = *right;
   |                                  ^^^^^^ move occurs because `*right` has type `Option<Box<Node<T>>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |
help: consider borrowing the `Option`'s content
   |
12 |             let right: Tree<T> = *right.as_ref();
   |                                        +++++++++
help: consider borrowing here
   |
12 |             let right: Tree<T> = &*right;
   |                                  ~~~~~~~
```

Hopefully this one is self-explanatory.

About the generic version, your assumption is indeed correct: no language can do recursive CPS with monomorphization, they all use dynamic dispatch (which is equivalent to `Box<dyn FnOnce()>` (or some GCed version), or to `&mut dyn FnMut()` or something similar). We will have to instantiate it ad infinitum.

Comment: That did indeed solve the problem. I thought I had tried most ways to add lifetime annotations to the parameters, but not the one that worked ;)

Comment: @ThomasMailund I added a short explanation (more precisely, confirmation) about the generic version. The most interesting thing is the `'a` lifetime you used and then dismissed: I _know_ the reason you introduced it, I also _know_ why you could let it go, and finally I _guess_ you don't know why (and I hope you would like to!), and I very much want to explain it! However, explaining that will make the answer _at least_ 2x, and it's already pretty long :( Maybe I'll come back to explain it later and edit the answer.

Comment: You are indeed right about the lifetimes